# Openid with an android app

Tags: android, openid

Is it possible to implement Openid in an android app? I'm currently developing an app that requires the user to log in and the people working on the back-end decided to use Openid as an easy way to allow users to register and log into their account. I've looked around but I didn't find a clear answer. Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: have a look at this:  http://openid.net/developers/